# Infinite Union of Sets with Content Zero

Tags: real-analysis

I believe that a countably infinite union of sets with content zero has content zero, but what about an uncountable union? I can't find anything in my textbook about countable union, but this is the way I "proved" it to myself, but I'm not sure if this proof is valid:

Let $S_{i}$, $i\in\mathbb{N}$ be a set with content zero and $T = \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}^{}{S_{i}}$

Simply find partition $P_{i}$ of $S_{i}$ such that $\sum_{j = 1}^{N_{i}}{ vol(P_{i,j})} < \alpha^{i} $ where $|\alpha| < 1$

Thus $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\sum_{j = 1}^{N_{i}}{ vol(P_{i,j})}} $$ $$< \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{ \alpha^{i} }$$

$$ = \frac{\alpha}{1 - \alpha} $$

given that $|\alpha| < 1$ and the above is a geometric series. This expression can be taken arbitrarily close to 0, so $T = \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}^{}{S_{i}}$ has content zero.

Is this valid?

Comment: Are you asking about *countable* or uncountable unions? Your question needs editing

Comment: $\cup_{x\in\mathbb R}\{x\} = \mathbb R$. This answers one of your interleaved questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is Jordan content?  Singletons have content zero,  but the set of rationals in $[0,1]$ has (outer) content $1$.

In your argument, you seem to get an *infinite* cover
$$
\{ P_{i,j}\,:\,1 \le j \le N_i, 1 \le i < \infty\}
$$
which is not allowed for the Jordan content.  This argument will be OK for Lebesgue measure, where countable covers are used.